# How to reconfigure Ambari services values with blueprint.json file

Tags: json, linux, hadoop, ambari, apiblueprint

we have many Ambari LAB clusters - Apache **Ambari Version 2.5.0.3** , while ambari agent installed on Linux redhat machines

my target is to find a way to update the values of services , on all the Ambari clusters , by automate the process

what we do until now , is take each ambari cluster and change the services values - but this take a lot of time

so if we have diff 25 ambari LAB clusters , then we need access each ambari cluster and change the values , this is very exhausting because we have a lot of values to change ...

but we have a new idea to automate the process

what we thinking is to generate a new blueprint.json from some ambari cluster file as the following:

```
curl -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET -u admin:admin http://{ambari_host}:8080/api/v1/clusters/{Cluster_name}\?format\=blueprint >  blueprint.json
```

then update/change the values in the new **blueprint.json** file

and finally upload/push the json file on all clusters

the big question is:

how to upload the new **blueprint.json**  file on ambari cluster ?

is it possible scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload blueprint file in the new cluster, below command can be used.

> curl -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" --data @blueprint.json -X POST -u admin:admin  http://<HOSTNAME>:8080/api/v1/blueprints/<BLUEPRINT_NAME>

update `<blueprintfile.json>` and `<BLUEPRINT_NAME>` in the command.

Comment: I intend to run the syntax in few min , but can you advice please how to find the BLUEPRINT_NAME ? or maybe BLUEPRINT_NAME is the blueprintfile.json file?

Comment: I successes to find the blue_printname  , but when I run - curl -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" --data @ -X POST -u admin:admin http://160.14.36.28:8080/api/v1/blueprints/HDP01 blueprint.json , its fail on  Warning: Couldn't read data from file "", this makes an empty POST.

Comment: I've updated the command, filename after --data @ was missing due to stackoverflow formatting, blueprint filename was missing in the command I shared. You can use any name for blueprint. blueprint.json is the name of the json file u created from the stable cluster.

Comment: @KingDavid , Were you able to go through the above comment ?